# Write JavaPairDStream to single HDFS location

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am exploring Spark Streaming using Java.

I current have Cloudera quick start VM (CDH 5.5) downloaded and I wrote a Java code for Spark streaming

I have written a program which returns JavaPairDStream. When I try to write the output to HDFS, it works but it is creating multiple folders (based on timestamp). The documentation says that this is how it is going to work, but is there a way to write the output to the same folder/file in HDFS? I tried to use repartition(1), but that did not work

Please see the code below:

```
      if (args.length < 3) {
      System.err.println("Invalid arguments");
      System.exit(1);
      }

  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Product Reco Spark Streaming");
  JavaStreamingContext javaStreamContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(10000));
  String inputFile = args[0];
  String outputPath = args[1];
  String outputFile = args[2];
  JavaDStream<String> dStream = javaStreamContext.textFileStream(inputFile);
  JavaPairDStream<String, String> finalDStream = fetchProductRecommendation(dStream); // Does some logic to get the final DStream
  finalDStream.print();
  finalDStream.repartition(1).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFiles(outputPath, outputFile, String.class, String.class, TextOutputFormat.class);
  javaStreamContext.start();
  javaStreamContext.awaitTermination();
```

To run this program, here is the command that I am using

```
spark-submit --master local /home/cloudera/Spark/JarLib_ProductRecoSparkStream.jar /user/ProductRecomendations/SparkInput/ /user/ProductRecomendations/SparkOutput/ productRecoOutput
```

Please let me know if you need more information since this is the first time I am writing a spark stream code.